# Did Moses (pbuh) raise the dead

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, agada-stories-legends, islam, resurrection-of-the-dead

This story is in the Quran, is it also in Jewish scripture?

> And when Moses said unto his people: Lo! Allah commandeth you that ye sacrifice a cow, they said: Dost thou make game of us? He answered: Allah forbid that I should be among the foolish! (2:67) They said: Pray for us unto thy Lord that He make clear to us what (cow) she is. (Moses) answered: Lo! He saith, Verily she is a cow neither with calf nor immature; (she is) between the two conditions; so do that which ye are commanded. (68) They said: Pray for us unto thy Lord that He make clear to us of what colour she is. (Moses) answered: Lo! He saith: Verily she is a yellow cow. Bright is her colour, gladdening beholders. (69) They said: Pray for us unto thy Lord that He make clear to us what (cow) she is. Lo! cows are much alike to us; and Lo! if Allah wills, we may be led aright. (70) (Moses) answered: Lo! He saith: Verily she is a cow unyoked; she plougheth not the soil nor watereth the tilth; whole and without mark. They said: Now thou bringest the truth. So they sacrificed her, though almost they did not. (71) And (remember) when ye slew a man and disagreed concerning it and Allah brought forth that which ye were hiding. (72) So We said: Strike the (dead body) with part of the (Sacrificed cow), thus Allah brings the dead to life, and He shows you His signs so that you may understand. (73)

The difference in the details are not important to me, but I would like to know if it is in your scripture, is the part about raising the dead included?

Comment: There's nothing in the Hebrew Bible that resembles this legend from the Quran.

Comment: Who is coming this as off topic? It's very on topic

Comment: @msh210 Some parts seem closer to Deuteronomy 21

Comment: @ba Eglah Arufah has nothing to do with color or ressurection either.

Comment: I meant "voting".  Darn autocorrect

Answer (score 2):

This is a total corruption of [Bamidbar 19 1-10](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9947). The cow is a pure **red** cow and does not have magic powers to resurrect the dead and has nothing to do with having killed someone. The **ashes** of the red heifer are used to purify a person who has become (spiritually) impure by touching a dead body. The dialogue is totally false as the Torah gives the command directly from Hashem.

Comment: Given that absolutely none of the details match except for the fact that there's a cow involved, it seems far more likely that the two passages are entirely unrelated rather than one being a "total corruption" of the other.